# jQuery Metadata selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, metadata

Hi I have lot of divs like this

```
<div class="card {toggle:'A'}">
<div class="card {toggle:'B'}">
<div class="card {toggle:'C'}">
<div class="card {toggle:'D'}">
```

Now I want to hide eg. B DIV. Im trying to

```
$(.class [toggle:A]).hide();
```

or some other combination, but nothig was working. Could you suggest any solution. Im using "Metadata - jQuery plugin for parsing metadata from elements".

Thanks a lot

Comment: Wy do you have such markup?

Comment: @undefined Apparently it's a plugin: https://github.com/jquery-orphans/jquery-metadata

Comment: Shouldn't he be able to then use the plugin to get the metadata back out?

Comment: metadata plugin was deprecated in 2011: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/04/16/official-plugins-a-change-in-the-roadmap/

Comment: I have old quite complicated jQuery project which is based on this markup. It is more effective to "break down" this question than rewrite it. This project is just funny game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

I didn't realize you were using the metadata plugin. You should be able to do something like

```
$("div.card").forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.metadata().toggle === 'B') {
        element.hide();
    }
});
```

### EDIT 2

[The metadata plugin was deprecated in 2011](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/04/16/official-plugins-a-change-in-the-roadmap/):

> "The Metadata plugin will be deprecated, in favor of similar
>   functionality provided by jQuery 1.4.3 and above."

Use jQuery's own [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead.

### ORIGINAL

This seems like you're doing something wrong upstream. Why are you storing data in the class attribute? One option to consider is to use [jquery's .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store stuff. I **strongly suggest** you take a look at doing something like that.

However, if you want to blindly plunge forward, I can help. CSS supports attribute selectors. In this case, you can use the `[rel$=foo]` form to match against the end of the class attribute:

```
$('div[class$="B\'}"]')
```

Note the messy escape characters involved.

A better solution is probably to use the `[rel*=foo]` form to match anywhere in the attribute:

```
$('div[class*="toggle:\'B\'"]')
```

I've made an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pabo/pxg0v8uq/

You can read a nice easy guide to attribute selectors here: http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have worked with `element.metadata().toggle` but I missed  "foreach" solution. Thanks a lot again pabo.

Comment: Im not author of this jQuery application. I just implement it to the page. This is some funny game. Solve this question is enough than rewrite whole application and test it.

Comment: Maybe it will help some newbies, like me. I has to use `$(this)` identification instead `element` this is my code, that works to me  `if ($(this).metadata().toggle === 'B') { $(this).hide(); }});`